# go error on make btcd: undefined: time.Until

Tags: go, bitcoin

I am trying to install btcd as part of LND.

I've already installed LND successfully: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

But when I go to make btcd I get this error:

```
# github.com/btcsuite/btcd
../../btcsuite/btcd/server.go:1564: /
make: *** [btcd] Error 2
```

How do I correct this error so that I can install and run btcd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time.Until function was [added only recently](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/20118). Make sure you use the latest version of Go. It seems that this function was added in Go version 1.8.